# How to change color of listbox in powershell on click?

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell

I have two listbox, ListBox1 and ListBox2

ListBox1 contains following items:
Red,
Blue,
Green

ListBox2 contains following items:
Red,
Yellow,
Green,
Purple,
Blue

and  I have a button called "Compare". So,this is what i want to accomplish. If
i click compare, the items in which are in ListBox2 but are present in ListBox1 (Yellow and Purple in this case) change their color to red or something else. Thank you

Comment: You'll need multi-threading and a method of shared state I believe. Powershell may not be the best tool for this, but you could potentially achieve what you want with `RunspacePool` and `[hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})`. I'd look into that, and if you're on Powershell 7, look into `ForEach-Object -Parallel`.

Comment: You'll need to use [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox) controls instead of normal TextBoxes. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835171/9898643) to see how you can add colored lines