# PushOutput from variable in powershell to textbox without having a button and handler click - Powershell GUI

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, user-interface

I build a windows forms in Powershell.

Inside that GUI I have the following function:

```
  function global:VPNCHECK {

        $VPN_Prozess = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Processname -eq "openvpn-gui" } | Out-Null
            
 

        if ($VPN_Prozess -eq "$null") {
                
            $txtOutputBox.add.Text( "VPN NOT RUNNING!")
            $txtOutputBox.ForeColor = "RED"
        }


        else {
                
            $txtOutputBox.add.Text( "VPN RUNNING!")
            $txtOutputBox.ForeColor = "GREEN"

        }
            
        $pingcheck = Test-Connection google.de -Count 1 | Out-Null
            

        if ($pingcheck -ne "$null") {

                
            $txtOutputBox.add.Text( "CONNECTED")
            $txtOutputBox.ForeColor = "GREEN"

        }

        else {

                
            $txtOutputBox.add.Text( "NO CONNECTION")
            $txtOutputBox.ForeColor = "RED"
                    
        }



    }
VPNCHECK
```

I want this output in my powershell textbox. But I didnt find a solution to add this to my windows text box when starting script without pressing a button with a click handler action. I also tried that with windows.forms.listbox .

My textbox:

```
 $txtOutputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $txtOutputBox.Location = '380, 600'
        $txtOutputBox.Multiline = $True
        $txtOutputBox.Name = 'txtOutputBox'
        $txtOutputBox.ReadOnly = $True
        $txtOutputBox.ScrollBars = $false
        $txtOutputBox.Size = '200, 100'
        $txtOutputBox.TabIndex = 14
        $form1.Controls.Add($txtOutputBox)
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english; greetings from Germany

F

Comment: `$txtOutputBox.add.Text( "VPN NOT RUNNING!")` doesn't look right, should be             `$txtOutputBox.Text = "VPN NOT RUNNING!"`. Remember to call `VPNCHECK` after creating `$txtOutputBox`

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how I can change the color?

Comment: Of the text? `ForeColor` is the right property for that. `BackColor` for background

Comment: But i just see one output, i think because i reset the variable $txtoutputbox.text with the output of ping check. how can I handle that? thanks

Comment: If you want to _add_ to the text box every time, do that: ```$txtOutputBox.Text = $txtOutputBox.Text,"New Line" -join "`n"```

Comment: thank you very much. It worked very good, except the colors. But I think i can fix it somehow

Comment: @Frxhb If you need colored lines, use a `RichTextBox` instead. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835171/9898643)