# How to put one or two certain colors in a richtextbox using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a command in PowerShell that displays the SMB1 Protocol and current antivirus status on a richtextbox. I also want some certain lines to be colored with red. I managed to displayed it all on the richtextbox but when I tried to color some of the lines, all of the outputs turned into red.

The code I was trying on the main code and didn't work out;

```
$RichTextBox.SelectionColor = [Drawing.Color]::Red
$RichTextBox.AppendText('some random text')
```

The main code itself;

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Set-Alias -Name Write-Host -Value Script_English -Scope Global
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = "1000,1000"
$Form.BackColor="#34495E"
$Form.Text="Testing"

$RichTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$RichTextBox.BackColor="darkblue"
$RichTextBox.ForeColor="white"
$RichTextBox.Multiline = $true
$RichTextBox.Width = 1650
$RichTextBox.Height = 650
$RichTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,150)
$RichTextBox.AutoSize=$true
$RichTextBox.Scrollbars = "Vertical"
$RichTextBox.ReadOnly=$true
$RichTextBox.Font="Arial,15"

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Text = "Start"
$Button.BackColor="#CCCCCC"
$Button.Width = 90
$Button.Height =30
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(900,900)

function Script_English {
    Write-Output "--- CHECKING ANTIVIRUS SOFTWARE ...---`r`n"
    Write-Output "`r`n"
    $Antivirus = wmic /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName | 
        findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"displayName"

    if ($Antivirus.Length -gt 0) {
        Write-Output "Antivirus Software is installed on your device:`r`n" 
        $Antivirus | Out-String
        #This is the first part I want to see it in red
    }
    else {
        Write-Output 'Antivirus Software is not installed on your device.`r`n'
    }

    # --- SMB Version Control ---
    Write-Output "`r`n"
    Write-Output "`r`n"
    $SMB1_Protocol_Check = Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol
    if ($SMB1_Protocol_Check -match "False") {
        Write-Output "SMB1 Protocol is disabled.That is good!`r`n"
    }
    elseif ($SMB1_Protocol_Check -match "True") {
        Write-Output "SMB1 Protocol is enabled. SMB1 is not secure, you should disable it!.`r`n"
        #This is the second part I want to see it  in red.
    }
    Write-Output "`r`n"
}

$Form.Controls.AddRange(@($RichTextBox,$Button))
$Button.Add_Click({ $RichTextBox.Text =Script_English })
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

The way I wanted to see it,

--- CHECKING ANTIVIRUS SOFTWARE ...---#white color

Antivirus Software is installed on your device: #red color

Windows Defender  #white color
McAfee VirusScan  #white color
Avast Antivirus   #white color

SMB1 Protocol is disabled. That is good!#white color

The outputs that came out,

--- CHECKING ANTIVIRUS SOFTWARE ...---#red color

Antivirus Software is installed on your device: #red color

Windows Defender  #red color
McAfee VirusScan  #red color
Avast Antivirus   #red color

SMB1 Protocol is disabled. That is good!#red color

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835171/9898643)

Comment: @Theo I have already checked it before posting the comment.Unfortunately,it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Just copy function [Append-ColoredLine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835171/9898643) on top of your script and if you want text to be shown in red just do

```
# change what the button click does into this
$Button.Add_Click({ Script_English })
```

Next, change your function `Script_English` into

```
function Script_English {
    $RichTextBox.Text = "---------------------------------------------CHECKING ANTIVIRUS SOFTWARE ...----------------------------------------------`r`n`r`n"
    # not sure if this is the best way to do this, but for now I'm leaving it as-is
    $Antivirus = wmic /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"displayName"
    if ($Antivirus.Length -gt 0) {
        $RichTextBox.AppendText("Antivirus Software is installed on your device:`r`n$($Antivirus | Out-String)"
    }
    else {
        Append-ColoredLine $RichTextBox Red "Antivirus Software is not installed on your device."
    }
    #----------------------------------------------------------- SMB Version Control ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $RichTextBox.AppendText("`r`n`r`n")
    $SMB1_Protocol_Check = Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EnableSMB1Protocol
    if(!$SMB1_Protocol_Check) {
        $RichTextBox.AppendText("SMB1 Protocol is disabled.That is good!`r`n")
    }
    else {
        Append-ColoredLine $RichTextBox Red "SMB1 Protocol is enabled. SMB1 is not secure, you should disable it!."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked however this solution caused a new problem.When testing the code,I realized that Antivirus names aligned themselves side by side,not  vertically.I used to deal with this issue by using "Out-String" command but I can't use that now. Would you give me and advise how to do that?

Comment: @Cino On mobile now, but please try my edit

Comment: The code is working now thanks for your contribution to this project.                                   Best Regards.

Comment: @Cino Thanks for the feedback. Being new to the platform, may I point you to the [tour], where amongst other things, you can read how to mark a question 'done' if it solves your problem.